# UserControl get updated data from MainWindow

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 UserControl, where the Usercontrol should get the Updated Data from MainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="BindingUserControl.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingUserControl.Pages"
    xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:BindingUserControl"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">


<Window.Resources>
    <local1:CommonViewModel x:Key="ABC"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <local:UserControl1 DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ABC}}" Margin="0,0,520.6,264"/>
    <TextBox  Width ="100" Height="100" Text="{Binding CommonProperity}"/>
    <Button Width="100" Height="100" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.85,1.404" Margin="139,208,554.6,112" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

UserControl

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingUserControl.Pages.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:BindingUserControl"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Local:CommonViewModel x:Key="ABC"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource ABC}}" >
    <TextBox Width="100" Height="100" Text="{Binding CommonProperity  ,Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Grid>
```

Viewmodel

```
namespace BindingUserControl
{
    class CommonViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string _Localtextdata;
        public string CommonProperity
        {
            get { return _Localtextdata; }
            set
            {
                _Localtextdata = value;
                INotifyPropertyChanged("CommonProperity");
            }
        }

        private void INotifyPropertyChanged(string ProperityName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(ProperityName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

}
```

There is no updated text in the usercontrol textbox when ever the Mainwindow textbox get any entry.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: The TextBox from MainWindow has no DataContext to bind to

Comment: You should read some tutorials about WPF and MVVM and Binding. From your code I see you got a lot of the concept totally wrong

Comment: Glad if you can point out where are the mistakes? May be also a link to a site where I can read and learn?

Answer (score 0):

You should only create *one* instance of `CommonViewModel` and let the `UserControl` inherit the `DataContext` from the window. Don't explicitly set the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` or any its child elements somewhere:

```
<Window x:Class="BindingUserControl.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BindingUserControl.Pages"
    xmlns:local1="clr-namespace:BindingUserControl"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <!-- Set the DataContext property -->
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local1:CommonViewModel x:Key="ABC"/>
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <local:UserControl1 Margin="0,0,520.6,264"/>
        <TextBox  Width ="100" Height="100" Text="{Binding CommonProperity}"/>
        <Button Width="100" Height="100" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.85,1.404" Margin="139,208,554.6,112" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```
<UserControl x:Class="BindingUserControl.Pages.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:Local="clr-namespace:BindingUserControl"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Width="100" Height="100" Text="{Binding CommonProperity  ,Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```